# How do I rewind an io.ReadCloser

Tags: http, go

I'm perpetually caught out by reading an **io.ReadCloser** and then forgetting that I've read it before, and when I read it again, I get an empty payload. I wish there was some lint check for my stupidity. Nonetheless, I think I can use TeeReader, but it fails to meet my expectations here:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        tee := io.TeeReader(r.Body, buf)
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(tee)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        log.Println("body", string(body))
        payload, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        log.Println("dump request", string(payload))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The body is missing from my "dump request" log line.

I.e. when I run `curl -i -X POST --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080`

I want the original request in full:

```
2019/01/14 11:09:50 dump request POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: curl/7.63.0

{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot rewind an `io.ReadCloser`, unless the underlying value is also an [`io.ReadSeeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadSeeker).

An `io.ReadCloser`, by very definition, has exactly two methods: `Read` and `Close`. So there is obviously there is no option to rewind.

An `io.ReadSeeker`, by contrast, has two methods: `Read` and `Seek`, the latter which allows rewinding.

If you need to accept only `io.ReadCloser`s which are also seekable, you can easily combine these two:

```
type ReadSeekCloser interface {
    io.Reader
    io.Seeker
    io.Closer
}
```

Now you can use your custom `ReadSeekCloser` type in place of an `io.ReadCloser`, and you'll have the option to rewind your reader.

Of course, few `io.ReadCloser`s in the wild actually conform to this interface (`os.File` will be the main one that does). If you have an `io.ReadCloser` that does not implement the `Seek` method (such as a network stream), probably the easiest way to make it `Seek`able is to dump the contents to a file, then open that file. There would be other ways to make an in-memory buffer seekable (`bytes.NewReader` for instance), but variations will require reading the stream into memory or onto disk, first.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I rewind a io.ReadCloser in Go[...]?

You cannot. A ReadCloser can be read and closed. Unless the actual underlying type has some method to rewind you simply cannot.
(For your case you may just use the bytes.Buffer, possibly after adding a Close method via io/ioutil.ReadCloser as the Request.Body; but this is not "rewinding" but "replacing".)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting. Are you saying for when I want to dump request, I concatenate "body"?

Comment: @hendry The request body is now in buf and body. Just use any of those two (buf of course) during dumping.

Comment: So there is no way to dump the request as I want, with out reading body first and appending. Urgh.

Comment: @hendry Of course not. How could that be possible? You can dump the body while reading (a TeeReader is fine here) but httputil.DumpRequest is for dumping a request and a request body can be read just once (which should be obvious).

Comment: Dumping the request is not obviously a one time action to be. Now I am puzzled how to concatenate body onto payload

Comment: @hendry A HTTP request is a stream and clearly not something which can be redone, especially the request body. I have to admit I do not understand what "concatenate body onto payload" could mean and what the actual problem you are trying to solve is.

Answer (score 1):

Request bodies aren't seek-able. There is no rewind, they aren't buffered in memory. When that data is read, it is read from the network stream. Imagine a large upload, buffering all of that data in memory by default would be wasteful.

That said, there are some things you can do to get the output you desire. It involves replacing r.Body after you've read it.

You mention wishing for a lint check. I've found that declaring a buffer and using only that buffer can help. If you like, you can even replace r.Body with that buffer. You will still need to remember to "rewind" with Seek.

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        b := &bytes.Buffer{}    
        _, err := io.Copy(b, r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        bodyCopy := bytes.NewReader(b.Bytes())
        log.Println("body", b.String())
        r.Body = io.NopCloser(bodyCopy)
        bodyCopy.Seek(0, 0)
        payload, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        log.Println("dump request", string(payload))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work. I get the following error: `cannot use &bytes.Buffer{} (type *bytes.Buffer) as type io.ReadSeeker in assignment: *bytes.Buffer does not implement io.ReadSeeker (missing Seek method)`

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest

> DumpRequest returns the given request in its HTTP/1.x wire representation. It should only be used by servers to debug client requests.

Clearly DumpRequest is for Dubug use.

But if you don't care about that. The godoc also metioned:

> If body is true, DumpRequest also returns the body. To do so, it consumes req.Body and then replaces it with a new io.ReadCloser that yields the same bytes.

So you can call DumpRequest first then ReadAll from Body, cause the Body is still the same after DumpRequest.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        payload, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        log.Println("dump request", string(payload))        

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        log.Println("body", string(body))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```